# Only allow one row with "main" flag up in a table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table as follows:

mysql> describe groups;

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| jobId              | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name               | varchar(45)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes              | varchar(1024) | YES  |     |         |                |
| main               | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There is another table, NOT relevant here, with jobs. This is the "child" table, 1:n for jobs. I want only ONE of these groups.

So, jobs will have several 'groups' entries; I want it so that only ONE of them, for a specific job, can be set as "1".

It's enforced in the code, but not in the DB right now.

Is it possible to enforce this at DB level?

Comment: You could change `main` to `bit(1) NULL` then create a unique index on `jobId, main`. Unfortunately this mean you cannot insert more than one zero per job and use NULL instead of zero.

Comment: I didn't think of that!

Comment: Please add it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique index on the pair of columns:

```
UNIQUE KEY uix_1 (jobid, main)
```

The unique index permits multiple NULL values nullable columns so the pair `(1, NULL)` could be inserted multiple times but the pair `(1, 1)` could be inserted only once.

If you want to constrain the values for `main` column to 1 and NULL you have some options:

- Use `CHECK` constraint – requires MySQL 8
- Use `ENUM('yes')` – using numbers as enum values have gotchas
- Create `FOREIGN KEY (main) REFERENCES main_values(main)`
- Use `BIT(1)` datatype – this will permits 0 as well